# mysql_num_rows(); and header(); gives redirect loop

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting a redirect loop error for using header(); after mysql_num_rows(); if I replace header(); with echo doesn't have a redirect loop error.

```
<?php

  require("includes/inc.php");

$id = trim(sanitize($_GET['id'])); //Receives the id of the file from the url

$fileid = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files WHERE fileid = '$id'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($fileid) != 1) {
        header('Location: download.php?error=invalid_file');
    } else {
        echo "File Exist";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Let me know if doesn't works

```
<?php

  require("includes/inc.php");

$id = trim(sanitize($_GET['id'])); //Receives the id of the file from the url

if($id)
{
    $fileid = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files WHERE fileid = '$id'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($fileid) != 1) {
        header('Location: download.php?error=invalid_file');
    } else {
        echo "File Exist";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: May i ask, what changes you made? And after header, an exit() should always be use.

Comment: You can see I have added a `if` condition. simple :)

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough information here. What's the name of the file above? And what is the PHP code in `download.php`? Are there any redirects in `includes/inc.php`?

Of course you don't get an error if you remove the `header()` call -- it's the `header('Location: download.php...')` that does the redirect.